# Import EPS and use as symbol

Tags: graphics

Is it possible to import a vector file & use as a symbol / plotmarker? I tried importing an EPS from Illustrator & assigning a name to it, but it failed. I would really like to be able to use it as a graphics primitive, and create designs by placing  them in exact positions / scaling, etc.. Is there a file size limitation?

*Mathematica* has a load of special characters like `[\BlackKing]`, etc. which are presumably .ttf files. Is it possible to add to this library?

Comment: `\[BlackKing]` is a character, so the last part is like asking if you can use your own custom font and the answer is that *Mathematica* doesn't care which font you use as long as it's installed on the system. See [Chess symbols in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode). As for custom plotmarkers this should certainly be possible, as evidenced by the documentation. I don't know where you went wrong but might be able to figure it out if you post an example. For the third question about placing objects within a graphics object, `Inset` comes to mind.

Comment: @Pickett thanks - will try to post an eg - thanks for the extra info too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think you can, using the `PlotMarkers -> {graphic, size}` option to the plotting functions. See the [documentation for `PlotMarkers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html) here for the details.

For instance, let's generate a colored pentagon, export it as an EPS file, and re-import it from that file:

```
Export["pentagon.eps", 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.05], Darker@Green}], 
   FaceForm[{Green, Opacity[0.1]}], Polygon[CirclePoints[5]]}]];

pentmark = Import["pentagon.eps"];

ListPlot[
 Table[{i, 2 i}, {i, -9, 9, 3}],
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], AspectRatio -> 1,

 PlotMarkers -> {pentmark, 0.1} (* here's where you choose the markers *)

]
```

[image: ListPlot with arbitrary markers]

**Update on** `CirclePoints[]`**:**

@martin pointed out that `CirclePoints` is new in version 10. The following function provides the same functionality:

```
circlepoints[n_] := Table[{Sin[2 Pi k/n], Cos[2 Pi k/n]}, {k, 0, n - 1}]
```

Comment: `CirclePoints` isn't built into mine, though `Polygon[Table[{Cos[2 \[Pi] k/6], Sin[2 \[Pi] k/6]}, {k, 0, 5}]]` works for me.

Comment: This works great, but when I try with my Illustrator eps `Import["C:\\Users.....\\splat.eps"]` it doesn't work ...

Comment: +1 I can confirm this works with eps generated from outside mathematica as well.

Comment: @martin That's an excellent point. I had not realized that `CirclePoints` was that new. I'll add your alternative to the answer.

Comment: @MarcoB is now working with extenal PDF but not EPS - strange, must be something I am doing in Illutrator.

Comment: If the simple `Import` is failing that's really  separate question. Do a search if folks have had issues with Illustrator/Eps and maybe post an example file.

Comment: @MarcoB is it possible to define a vector image created outside mathematica as a graphics primitive?

Comment: @george2079 pdf is working fine - think I'll settle with that :)

Comment: @martin I think it is possible to do that. As a matter of fact, I think that's what we did here, in a way! However, the internal representation of my re-imported pentagon is not a `Polygon` primitive anymore: `Import` re-interpreted it as the superposition of two other graphics primitives, a `JoinedCurve` and a `FilledCurve`. You can inspect the structure of the imported objects using e.g. `InputForm[ object ]` to see what the internal representation is.

Comment: @MarcoB ah, great! thanks - will follow up on those suggestions :)